# FormsAuthentication.SignOut() does not want to redirect to logout view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I am trying to redirect to a logout view when the user clicks on logout but mvc intercepts the redirection.

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
return RedirectToAction("Logout", "Account"); 
}

public ActionResult Logout()
{
return View("LogOff");
}
```

Id like the LogOff view to be displayed after logout

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have marked the complete account controller with the `Authorize` attribute. You should decorate only the actions that required authorization with that.

Comment: Kind of hard to logon if that's the case, but it was my initial idea too!